# Get words in parenthesis as a group regex

Tags: python, regex

**String1:** `{{word1|word2|word3 (word4 word5)|word6}}`

**String2:** `{{word1|word2|word3|word6}}`

With this regex sentence:

`(?<=\{\{)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\}\})`

I capture **String2** as groups. How can I change the regex sentence to capture `(word4 word5)` also as a group?

Comment: How about just grab anything that isn't a  { } | ( ) and \n character `[^{}|\(\)\n]+`  https://regex101.com/r/rC3aiC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `(?:\s*(\([^()]*\)))?` subpattern:

```py
(?<=\{\{)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s*(\([^()]*\)))?\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\}\})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ceSYmK/1).

The `(?:\s*(\([^()]*\)))?` part is an optional non-capturing group that matches one or zero occurrences of

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `)` - end of the group.

If you need to make sure only whitespace separated words are allowed inside parentheses, replace `[^()]*` with `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*` and insert `(?:\s*(\(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\)))?`:

```py
(?<=\{\{)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s*(\(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\)))?\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\}\})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ceSYmK/2).

Comment: why not `(?<=\{\{)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(\s*\([^()]*\))*)\|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\}\})`?

Comment: @GhostOps That will introduce an extra capturing group.

Comment: but OP said *How can I change the regex sentence to capture (word4 word5) also as a group?*

Comment: @GhostOps Sorry, I see the problem now. I added the group to the current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the expression by matching the desired substrings rather than capturing them. For that you could use the following regular expression.

```
(?<=[{| ])\w+(?=[}| ])|\([\w ]+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JwwS0N/1) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python demo](https://replit.com/@CarySwoveland/NavajowhiteMysteriousSign#main.py)

The elements of the expression are as follows.

```
(?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
  [{| ]  # match one of the indicated characters
)        # end the positive lookbehind
\w+      # match one or more word characters
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  [}| ]  # match one of the indicated characters
)        # end positive lookahead
|        # or
\(       # match character
[\w ]+   # match one or more of the indicated characters 
\)       # match character
```

Note that this does not validate the format of the string.